# ¿Cómo muestro la posición de un numero con la matriz?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Solo me falta la ubicación del numero mayor, es decir la fila y la columna

```
int arreglo[3][2];
int arreglo1[3][2];
int fila, columna;
int a=-1;
int b=-1;   
int maxfilas=3, maxcolumnas=2;
int contador;
```

ya declare las variables y ahora puse el código para que guarde los números que agrego

```
for(fila=0;fila<maxfilas;fila++){
    for(columna=0; columna<maxcolumnas;columna++){
        printf("Teclee el valor del arreglo[%d][%d]: ", fila,columna);
        scanf("%d", &arreglo[fila][columna]);
    }
}   
for(fila=0;fila<maxfilas;fila++){
    for(columna=0; columna<maxcolumnas;columna++){
        printf("El valor de arreglo [%d][%d] es %d\n", fila, columna, arreglo[fila][columna]);
    }
}
```

Hasta aquí tengo la información de los números
Pero después solo me guarda el numero mayor pero no la posición

```
for(fila=0;fila<maxfilas;fila++){
    for(columna=0; columna<maxcolumnas;columna++){
        if(arreglo[fila][columna]>contador){
            a=fila;
            a=columna;
            contador=arreglo[fila][columna];
        }
    }
}
printf("El valor del mayor es %d y esta en el arreglo [%d][%d]", contador, arreglo[fila][columna]);
```

Comment: Ten dos variables:` int a=0,b=0;` y cuando el if se cumpla le asigna a ambas el valor de filas y columnas:`if(arreglo[fila][columna]>contador){a=fila;b=columna;contador=arreglo[fila][columna];} ` y luego lo sacas por `printf`: `printf("El valor del mayor es %d y esta en el arreglo [%d][%d]", contador,a,b);`.

Comment: Tu código está bueno, el único problema es que el `printf` final debería enseñarte caracteres raros y colgarte la App.:( , porque le indicas que hay más argumentos de lo que realmente le pasas: `("%d%d%d",contador,array[fila][columna]);` como ves hay tres indicadores de enteros, eso puede causar estrago en tu programa y termina ejecutándose sin poder terminar, explicaría a profundidad el porqué, pero nunca me especialice en eso, pero aquí va un intento:

Comment: Cuando pasas un parámetro por medio de una función el compilador realmente lo mete en una pila(Stack) dentro de esa pila esta la IP que después será recuperada al final de la función y se llamará a la instrucción goto para regresar el código en donde lo dejaste. Ahora vamos con printf: Metes primero el mensaje con el indicador:` "msg: %d%c%d"`, entonces cuando la función printf lee esto saca un entero un `char y un entero`, pero ¿Qué pasas si le pasé menos parámetro que debía("%d%d%d",contador,array[fila][columna])?: Pasa lo siguiente:

Comment: El compilador primero saca la cadena, la analiza y cuando consigue lo que yo llamo indicadores: %d, etc... . Saca de la pila lo que hay y aumenta la dirección de la pila 4(sizeof(int32bits)=4), saca y saca, pero como solo hay dos parámetros lo último que saca es la IP del programa.0_0 y al hacer goto el puntero del programa no sabe a donde ir y termina cerrándose o se ejecutará para siempre, lo que suceda primero:). Espero que te sirva mi explicación, no es del todo correcta pero hay dejo la idea.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, si me sirvió lo que me dijiste y ya logre obtener la posición. DTB.

Answer (score 1):

> Pero después solo me guarda el numero mayor pero no la posición

No es cierto, te guarda todo pero sólo usas parte de la información que tienes. Seguramente querías hacer esto:

```
printf("El valor del mayor es %d y esta en el arreglo [%d][%d]", arreglo[fila][columna], fila, columna);
```